# Getting the HTML of an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to get the entire HTML of an element using jQuery. Of course, `.html()` grabs only the inner HTML, but I wanted to retrieve the wrapping HTML too.

Imagine the following HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container_a">
        <p>Container A</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container_b">
        <p>Container B</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, If I would do `$("#container_a").html()` I'd get `<p>Container A</p>` clearly. However, I want to get the following:

```
<div id="container_a">
    <p>Container A</p>
</div>
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. Google let me down on my search :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `prop`:

```
$("#container_a").prop('outerHTML');
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HeDWn/)

Comment: Nice to see there's a jQuery-ish way (albeit it really seems like a bit of overkill, tbh) ... now I'm going to have to sift through the source code to see if `prop()` is actually proxying ...

Comment: @vzwick Any update on that so far?

Comment: @vzwick All it really does is "fix" some things (like trying to access the `class` property, it changes it to `className` internally), but ends up just returning `element[ name ]`

Answer (score 1):

use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

```
$("#container_a")[0].outerHTML
```

using plain javascript

```
document.getElementById("container_a").outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

First use `clone` for temporary then get `html`

```
$('div').append($('#container_a').clone()).html();
```

Comment: this solution as i'm aware of is the only one which work on older jquery/browser versions

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<script>
    var a=document.getElementById("container_a").outerHTML;
    alert(a);
</script>
```

Instead of alert we may use variable a in any other way...

Answer (score 0):

use `outerHTML`

```
$("#container_a")[0].outerHTML
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/uBDHY/1/

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

you can use .`outerHTML` for this

```
$("#container_a")[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: `$("#container_a")` - the `#` makes a difference.

Comment: @vzwick Thanks i updated it